# An exception occurred while initializing the database with data

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5

I am preparing a rest API with ASP.net

I started initializing the database tables with data, but I get this error:

`An exception occurred while initializing the database`.

The problem is that the data is in tables, only one table "Event", in which I get this problem, this is my code to initialize the database:

```
 var FeedTypes = new List<FeedType>  
 {  
   new FeedType{Libel="FeedType1"},  
 };  

 FeedTypes.ForEach(s =>  
 {  
   s.ObjectState = Repository.Pattern.Infrastructure.ObjectState.Added;  
   context.FeedTypes.Add(s);  
   context.SaveChanges();  

 });  

 var feedtypeee = context.FeedTypes.Where(s => s.Libel == "FeedType1").First().Id;  
 var Feeds = new List<Feed>  
 {  
    new Feed{Libel="Libel1", Content="contentnotif1" , CreatedDate=Convert.ToDateTime("2013-04-24 17:47:03"), UserSMAId=ccv, FeedTypeId=feedtypeee , ImageId=context.Images.Where(i=>i.Alt=="Image 1").FirstOrDefault().Id},  
 };  

 Feeds.ForEach(s =>  
 {  
   s.ObjectState = Repository.Pattern.Infrastructure.ObjectState.Added;  
   context.Feeds.Add(s);  
   context.SaveChanges();  
 });  

 var FeedComments = new List<FeedComment>  
 {  
    new FeedComment{Content="Content1", CreatedDate=Convert.ToDateTime("2013-04-24 17:47:03"), FeedId=context.Feeds.Where(s=>s.Libel=="Libel1").FirstOrDefault().Id, UserSMAId=ccv},       
 };  

 FeedComments.ForEach(s =>  
 {  
   s.ObjectState = Repository.Pattern.Infrastructure.ObjectState.Added;  
   context.FeedComments.Add(s);  
   context.SaveChanges();  
 });  

 var Events = new List<Event> {   
   new Event{   
     Begin=Convert.ToDateTime("2013-04-24 17:47:03"),  
     End=Convert.ToDateTime("2013-04-24 17:47:03"), UserSMAId=ccv  
   },  
 };  

 Events.ForEach(s =>  
 {  
   s.ObjectState = Repository.Pattern.Infrastructure.ObjectState.Added;  
   context.Events.Add(s);  
   context.SaveChanges();  
 });
```

This is my code for each entity:

```
public partial class FeedType : BaseEntity
{
    public string Libel { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Feed> Feeds { get; set; }

    public FeedType()
    {
        Feeds = new List<Feed>();
    }
}

public partial class Feed : BaseEntity
{
    public string Libel { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("UserSMAId")]
    public virtual UserSMA UserSMA { get; set; }
    public Int64 UserSMAId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("FeedTypeId")]
    public virtual FeedType FeedType { get; set; }
    public Int64 FeedTypeId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ImageId")]
    public virtual Image Image { get; set; }
    public Int64 ImageId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<FeedComment> FeedComments { get; set;        }

    public Feed()
    {
        FeedComments = new List<FeedComment>();
    }
}

public partial class FeedComment : BaseEntity
{
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("FeedId")]
    public Feed Feed { get; set; }
    public Int64 FeedId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("UserSMAId")]
    public UserSMA UserSMA { get; set; }
    public Int64 UserSMAId { get; set; }
}

public partial class Event : Feed
{
    public DateTime Begin { get; set; }
    public DateTime End { get; set; }

    // SMA.Entities.Models.Event.UserSMAId hides 
    [ForeignKey("UserSMAId")]
    public virtual UserSMA UserSMA { get; set; } 
    // inherited member 'SMA.Entities.Models.Feed.UserSMAId
    public Int64 UserSMAId { get; set; } //Use the new keyword if hiding was intended
}
```

Have you please any idea about the problem? How can I present the relation betwwen the Event and Feed Classes?

**Update**

`SMAContext.cs` file:

```
public DbSet<Event> Events { get; set; }
public DbSet<Feed> Feeds { get; set; }
public DbSet<FeedComment> FeedComments { get; set; }
public DbSet<FeedType> FeedTypes { get; set; }

protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Feed>()
        .Map(m => m.ToTable("Feeds"))
        .Map<Event>(m => m.ToTable("Events"));

}
```